# JNI function name if class exist in class

Tags: java, java-native-interface

MethodNameJNI function may look like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
     //...
}
```

**In my code on the Java side is:**

```
public class ClassName
{
    private class ClassName2
    {
        MethodName();
    }
}
```

I don't know, how write name of the native function; any combination go to link error:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_ClassName2_MethodName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName2_MethodName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
```

Comment: Just use the javah tool to do this for you.

Comment: where is this `MethodName()` ? And how exactly are you calling it inside the inner class?

Comment: first steps in objective after long time in pure C... :)

Comment: ...that was bad idea, I just know the answer:r

In 'C' module:

**JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);**

In Java, inside ClassName2

**ClassName.this.MethodName();**

Comment: The answer is correct, why no accept it?

Answer (score 5):

Using javah, it looks like the function name gets the standard OuterClass$InnerClass with the $ expanded to its unicode digits:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_00024ClassName2_MethodName(JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

Ugly, but that should work.

Comment: My hero as well, nice one.